# How to get number for duplicate value in associative array at the same time need to remove duplicate value from it?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to get the number of duplicate values (`array['name']`) in associative array and at the same time I need to remove these duplicate values from it.

Actual array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 123
        [name] => hello
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 124
        [name] => hello
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 125
        [name] => hello1
    )
```

Expected:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 123
        [name] => hello
        [name_count] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 125
        [name] => hello1
        [name_count] => 1
    )
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why take 123 and not 124?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `array_merge` and `array_values` functions:

```
$names = [];
foreach ($arr as $v) {   // $arr is your initial array
    if (!isset($names[$v['name']])) {
        $names[$v['name']] = array_merge(['name_count' => 1], $v);
    } else {
        $names[$v['name']]['name_count']++;
    }
}
$names = array_values($names);

print_r($names);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/624745)